# How to retrieve rows through a for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

```
[4*x1*f1   5*f2;    10*f1/x2     f2*x1*x2]
```

I have a 2x2 matrix, but I need to retrieve each row individually.  How would I loop over it so that MATLAB can find the length of the matrix, and keep the loop open until the index is equal to the number of rows in said matrix?  It seems that MATLAB functions were designed pre-packaged to iterate over rows, but I need to write a custom function for myself.

Comment: `for r=1:size(A,1)`?

Comment: See: [Matrix Indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are interested in the syntax `A(1,:)` to get row 1, etc.

```
A = [4*x1*f1   5*f2;    10*f1/x2     f2*x1*x2];
[r,~] = size(A);  % get the number of rows, save as 'r'
for i = 1:r  %% loop over the number of rows
    row = A(i,:);  %% save the individual row
    %% my_func(row)   <<-- put whatever code you want here
end
```